# Linq Query Where() with Date subtraction taking excessive time

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using C# and entity framework 6.

I have an entity (Animal) in my database that has a list of another entity (Feeding) attached to it. The Feeding entity has a DateTime associated with it.

My query looks like this:

```
var sum = animal.Feedings.Where(f => (DateTimeOffset.Now.Date- f.DateTime.Date).Days == 1).Select(f => f.Amount).Sum()
```

I basically want the summation of the total feeding amount from yesterday. But if my Animal object has a significantly large amount of feedings (say 5000, which is expected and could be even higher), this line is taking 20+ seconds to complete.

Is there a way to refactor this line of code to be more efficient?

**EDIT**
It appears to be the Feedings object being lazy loaded from the animal object.

```
var feedings = animal.Feedings
```

This line is what now takes the excessive time. The animal object was originally created from an AsQueryable() object, by selecting the animal by an ID.

**EDIT #2**
This logic is inside the Animal Repository and cannot access the DBContext, it can only access an IQueryable of the Animal collection. I also do not have access to EF's Include() function to try to include the feedings with the query.

Comment: Create view, UDF or SP on db and then select from created query. In this way you can take sql performance

Comment: Where exactly is the delay happening. On the c# level or on the DB level? Make sure the delay is not the DB, if so try to optimize the table for your linq query (indexes, etc.).

Comment: If the `animal` is already loaded object (as it seems), most likely the time is taken by lazy loading the `Feedings` collection. Did you try `var feedings = animal.Feedings;` and see how long it takes, and then measure the LINQ query, which should be a LINQ to Objects query and for 5K items should run in milliseconds.

Comment: It is the Feedings collection lazy loading, I added a line for var feedings = animal.Feedings and it was what took the excessive time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slow part is loading the `Feedings` collection. If it's already loaded, the LINQ to Objects query will run very fast.

If you have access to the `DbContext`, instead of loading the collection you can execute the query inside the database like this:

```
var date = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1));
var sum = dbContext.Entry(animal).Collection(e => e.Feedings).Query()
    .Where(f => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f.DateTime) == date)
    .Sum(f => f.Amount);
```

Having access to `IQueryable<Animals>` (as mentioned in the comments and the update) will also work. Just instead of

```
dbContext.Entry(animal).Collection(e => e.Feedings).Query()
```

you would use something like this

```
animals.Where(a => a.Id == animal.Id).SelectMany(a => a.Feedings)
```

The rest is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately this logic is inside of the animal repository, and cannot access the DB Context. It can only access an IQueryable of the Animal collection.

Comment: Something like `IQueryable<Animal> Animals`?

Comment: Btw, these "repositories" seem to introduce more problems than solving them (IMO). Or at least make the easy things harder if not impossible.

Comment: Doing SelectMany off of the animals object is causing the same slowness as the animal.Feedings.

Comment: Didn't you say `IQueryable` and not `IEnumerable`? The queryables execute in database.

Comment: Anyway, I gave you the only possible options to ptimize this in EF. You need either (A) access to `DbContext`, or (B) access to the  `DbSet<Animal>` exposed as `IQueryable<Animal>`, or (C) live with the current implementation and performance. There is no other way.

Comment: It's IQueryable, it did halve the time. This solution will be temporary until we can revamp our repositories. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on DateTime, then try

```
 var startDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;
 var endDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date;

 var sum = animal.Feedings
    .Where(f => (f.DateTime >= startDate && f.DateTime < endDate))
    .Select(f => f.Amount)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)   // don't throw an error if the query has no results
    .Sum();
```